# $f$ is differentiable at the point $\hat{x}$: $f(x)-f(\hat{x}) = h(x) \cdot (x-\hat{x})$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ an open set, $f : U \to \mathbb{R}$ and
>   $\hat{x} \in U$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at the point
>   $\hat{x}$ if and only if there exists a continuous function $h : U \to
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ at the point $\hat{x}$ and such that $f(x)-f(\hat{x}) =
>  h(x) \cdot (x-\hat{x})$ for all $x \in U$.

I know that the differentiability of $f$ is equivalent to $f(x)-f(\hat{x}) = \nabla f(\hat{x})\cdot (x-\hat{x})+ r(x-\hat{x})$ with $\lim_{x \to \hat{x}} \frac{r(x-\hat{x})}{\|x-\hat{x}\|} = 0$.

I am stuck on this problem for a good while. Is anyone could help me to solve this problem?

Comment: what definition of differentiability are you using?

Comment: you say that it is equivalent to some expression being fulfilled, but you may have some kind of definition of it as well. for instance, $\nabla f$ could be defined in whatever suitable way. if you use the formulation you want to prove as a definition of differentiability (some authors do this) then it is a fairly easy exercise.

Comment: Sincerely, scuse me! Intuitively, I think it is better to use the main definition in the question where $\nabla f(\hat{x})$ is simply the gradient of $f$ at $\hat{x}$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully one way is ok, that if such an $h$ exists then $f$ is differentiable. For the other way, write
$$r(x-\hat{x}) = R(x-\hat{x}) \cdot (x-\hat{x}),$$
eg $R(y) = r(y) y / {\| y \|^2}$ for $(y = x - \hat{x})$, so $R$ is defined everywhere and $R(x-\hat{x}) \to 0$ as $x \to \hat{x}$. Now you have
$$ f(x) - f(\hat{x}) = \nabla f(\hat{x}) \cdot (x-\hat{x}) + R(x - \hat{x}) \cdot (x-\hat{x}).$$
Can you now determine what $h$ should be? (Note that $h$ is allowed to depend on $\hat{x}$!)

Comment: Thank for your answer BTW. I don't know how you obtain this result :$r(x-\hat{x}) = R(x-\hat{x}) \cdot (x-\hat{x})$. Could you explain to me where it comes from?

Comment: Yeah, sorry if that's not clear. I'm *defining* R in that way. Take my definition of $R(y)$, and see if it satisfies my claim equation (applied: it does!) :)

Comment: I work hard to find this $h$, but I block on this problem. Could you help me  a bit more?

Comment: When you write $r(y)y$, do you mean $\frac{r(y) ||y||}{||y||^2}$$?

Comment: Not quite. You have to make sure that you're adding vectors to vectors, not a scalar to a vector. So by "$r(y) y$", I simply mean the *vector* $y$, multiplied (or 'scaled') by the *scalar* $r(y)$. Note that $f(x)$ is a scalar ($\in \mathbb{R}$), so $r(y)$ must also be. Does this help? :)